# How to launch my app by typing the name of the app?

Tags: android

By clicking Link my of app on webpage it launch app properly. But I want when some one type name of my app in web browser it should launch my app instead of searching for app on google..
Currently I m doing this by using intent filter...

Actually I want when some type name of app in web browser "myapp_name:http://www.google.com" my app should launch and main_activity should get url(www.google.com or http:google.com) for further process.

Comment: Where are you planning on typing this? If you are planning on typing that into some app that you did not write, how do you plan to force that app's developers to launch your app?

Comment: In web browser.

Answer (score 1):

There is no requirement for a Web browser to launch an app based on the user typing in a URL in the browser's address bar. In fact, I know of no browsers that support this, though some might exist.